# eslint: Unable to resolve path to module 'p-queue'

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have updated my version of `p-queue` from 6.6.0 to 7.3.4, but by doing so I got an eslint error when importing this dependency:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: p-queue 7+ is a pure ESM module, so you'll need to tell ESLint how to resolve those. Better yet, don't upgrade unless you need to.

Comment: p-queue 6 introduced some security issues, and in their repo they said: `We will backport security fixes to v6 for the foreseeable future.`, however, how can I tell ESLint how to resolve p-queue ?